# How to make a vb application work with a SQL database from any computer?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Most of my programming experience is c-based, so I don't have the clearest understanding of how SQL (specifically, the mySQL platform) works. 
My vb.net application works completely fine on the computer I made it on. However, if I download it onto another computer, the mySQL connection fails to open. From what I've read on other StackOverflow posts, that's the fault of the connection string. My connection string looks something like this:

> "server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;uid=username;pwd=password;database=db;default command timeout=300"

Again, for the base computer, this works fine without any problems at all. It's when I run the program from a different computer when I run into trouble. Do I need to change the server number? I've tried doing that, but the program still doesn't work. Is there one more field I need to add into the string? Or do I need to configure mySQL settings in some way on each computer? I would like to change the program in a way that allows anybody to use it immediately upon download. Would any of the methods listed above work, or a completely different one entirely?

Thanks.

Comment: Private network or "anyone" meaning anyone in the world? Publicly accessible databases are generally considered a bad idea (security wise) in my experience.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I did mean "private network" when I said "anyone". Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Usually, the IP address ("server") just needs to be something all expected clients can get to unobstructed. However, MySQL users can be set up with client ip restrictions, and network security can get in the way as well.

Comment: Applications like this require some kind of configuration to work, either a control-panel type configuration screen or, for example, a `.ini` file they can edit.

Comment: .NET applications have a config file and that is where connection strings are usually stored.  A number of automated tools, including the MySQL tools for VS, will create connection strings there for you.  When you deploy your application, the user can edit that config file by hand or you can edit it in code to modify the connection string appropriate.  You can find an example of the code option [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?532768-NET-2-0-Protected-Configuration-(Encrypting-Config-Files)).

Comment: You should also go [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) to learn exactly what constitutes a valid connection string.  That will allow you to edit yours to connect to the desired database.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple class I use with MySQL. Replace everything in [bracket] by your values. if It's not working look at your firewall and also use MySQL WorkBench to create user/password/permission/schema. Make sure you can connect to your database with MySQL workbench then you know you have everything setup right.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class mysql

    'Connection string for mysql
    Public SQLSource As String = "Server=[x.x.x.x];userid=[yourusername];password=[yourpassword];database=[defaultdatabaseifany];"

    'database connection classes

    Private DBcon As New MySqlConnection
    Private SQLcmd As MySqlCommand
    Public DBDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Public DBDT As New DataTable
    ' parameters
    Public Params As New List(Of MySqlParameter)

    ' some stats
    Public RecordCount As Integer
    Public Exception As String

    Function ExecScalar(SQLQuery As String) As Long
        Dim theID As Long
        DBcon.ConnectionString = SQLSource
        Try
            DBcon.Open()
            SQLcmd = New MySqlCommand(SQLQuery, DBcon)
            'loads params into the query
            Params.ForEach(Sub(p) SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.ParameterName, p.Value))

            'or like this is also good
            'For Each p As MySqlParameter In Params
            ' SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.ParameterName, p.Value)
            ' Next
            ' clears params
            Params.Clear()
            'return the Id of the last insert or result of other query
            theID = Convert.ToInt32(SQLcmd.ExecuteScalar())
            DBcon.Close()

        Catch ex As MySqlException
            Exception = ex.Message
            theID = -1
        Finally
            DBcon.Dispose()
        End Try
        Return theID
    End Function

    Sub ExecQuery(SQLQuery As String)

        DBcon.ConnectionString = SQLSource
        Try
            DBcon.Open()
            SQLcmd = New MySqlCommand(SQLQuery, DBcon)
            'loads params into the query
            Params.ForEach(Sub(p) SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.ParameterName, p.Value))

            'or like this is also good
            'For Each p As MySqlParameter In Params
            ' SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.ParameterName, p.Value)
            ' Next
            ' clears params

            Params.Clear()
            DBDA.SelectCommand = SQLcmd
            DBDA.Update(DBDT)
            DBDA.Fill(DBDT)

            DBcon.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            Exception = ex.Message
        Finally
            DBcon.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
    ' add parameters to the list
    Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
        Dim NewParam As New MySqlParameter(Name, Value)
        Params.Add(NewParam)
    End Sub
End Class
```